# How to use Numbers and whitespace in xmlID xmlIDREF JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following classes:

```
   @XmlRootElement
   @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
   public class Employee {

   @XmlAttribute
   @XmlID
   private String id;

   public String getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public Employee getManager() {
      return manager;
   }

   public void setManager(Employee manager) {
     this.manager = manager;
   }

   public List<Employee> getReports() {
      return reports;
   }

   public void setReports(List<Employee> reports) {
     this.reports = reports;
   }

  @XmlAttribute
  private String name;

  @XmlIDREF
  private Employee manager;

  @XmlElement(name="report")
  @XmlIDREF
  private List<Employee> reports;

  public Employee() {
      reports = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  }
}
```

The Company class:

```
  @XmlRootElement
  @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
  public class Company {

  @XmlElement(name="employee")
  private List<Employee> employees;

  public Company() {
      employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
  } 

  public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
      return employees;
  }
}
```

My main contains the following:

```
    Employee employee1 = new Employee();
    employee1.setId("1");
    employee1.setName("Jane Doe");
    company.getEmployees().add(employee1);

    Employee employee2 = new Employee();
    employee2.setId("2");
    employee2.setName("John Smith");
    employee2.setManager(employee1);
    employee1.getReports().add(employee2);
    company.getEmployees().add(employee2);

    Employee employee3 = new Employee();
    employee3.setId("3");
    employee3.setName("Anne Jones");
    employee3.setManager(employee1);
    employee1.getReports().add(employee3);
    company.getEmployees().add(employee3);
```

If I marshall this it runs fine. But if I create the following schema and then add the schema in the main then I get the following errors:

Schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xs:element name="company" type="company"/>

    <xs:complexType name="company">
    <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="employee" type="employee" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="employee">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="manager" type="xs:IDREF" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="report" type="xs:IDREF" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:ID"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Error Received:**

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '1' is not a valid value for 'NCName'.]

I am aware this is because NCName cannot start with a number and have whitespaces. But in my case the id is a number.

**I want to know:**
1) Why does this only happen when I include the schema?
2) What is the workaround, and is the only way to use moxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Setting an XML Schema using marshaller.setSchema(schema); turns on validation against that XML Schema, and you know that an all-digit ID value is invalid.

2) You can use an Adapter.

Add an annotation in Employee.java:

```
@XmlAttribute
@XmlID
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Adapter.class)
private String id;
```

And you'll need this simple class:

```
public class Adapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {
  @Override
  public String marshal(String s) throws Exception {
    return "_" + s;
  }
  @Override
  public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
    return v.substring(1);
  }
}
```

The resulting XML will be correct according to XML Schema:

```
<company>
  <employee id="_1" name="Jane Doe">
    <report>_2</report>
    <report>_3</report>
  </employee>
  <employee id="_2" name="John Smith">
    <manager>_1</manager>
  </employee>
  <employee id="_3" name="Anne Jones">
    <manager>_1</manager>
  </employee>
</company>
```